# problemas controles HTML em uma pagina web com VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

estou tentando preencher os controles em uma pagina web com uma interação entre VBA e o IE, não estou conseguindo encontrar e popular os campos referentes a data de vigência da ata.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

URL Da Pagina: http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/Livre/Ata/ConsultaAta00.asp

Codigo VBA:

```
Sub x()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim C
    Dim ULogin As Boolean, ieForm
    Dim MyPass As String, MyLogin As String

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/Livre/Ata/ConsultaAta00.asp"

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop


    ie.Document.getElementsByName("dt_ini").Value = "12/12/2012" 'o erro ocorre aqui
    ie.Document.getElementsByName("dt_fim").Value = "12/11/2011" 'o erro ocorre aqui

End Sub

Sub Referencia()
    Dim ObRef
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Adiciona Controles da Net
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B}", 1, 1
End Sub
```

Comment: gente descobri que as tags em questão estão dentro de um frame chamado **main2**

Comment: se achou útil vote na resposta! rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o erro estava acontecendo pois as tags estavam dentro de uma Frame, a solução ficou assim:

```
Sub x()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim objCollection
    Dim ULogin As Boolean, ieForm
    Dim MyPass As String, MyLogin As String

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "http://comprasnet.gov.br/acesso.asp?url=/Livre/Ata/ConsultaAta00.asp"

    Do Until ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set objCollection = ie.Document.frames(1).Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    i = 0



    Do While i < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(i).Name = "dt_ini" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = "12/12/2015"
        End If

        If objCollection(i).Name = "dt_fim" Then
            objCollection(i).Value = "11/12/2016"
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop


End Sub

Sub Referencia()
    Dim ObRef
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Adiciona Controles da Net
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B}", 1, 1
End Sub
```